# Rotate apache logs based on file size in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, shell, logging

I have three sites on my server and their logs (Apache logs) are in their root folder not in /var/log. I need a script that rotates the access_log and error_log base on their file size for example rotates them when their file size exceeds 1G .

Server's OS is Ubuntu.

I have a basic skill of shell programing but good talent in learing ;)
would you help me in this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) can be configured tn only rotate when logs exceed a certain size, see the minsize option. Typically logrotate runs daily though, if you wanted to rotate when the logfile was more or less exactly 1GB, you might need a script which watches the logfile and triggers logrotate when it exceeds your limit.

Alternatively, you could stick with daily rotation of smaller logfiles, but have a postrotate script which concatenates the rotated logs together into 1GB clumps of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [managelogs](http://freshmeat.net/projects/managelogs) exactly for that.
It will automatically rotate the logs when the limit is reached.
It also has other neat features like directly writing to compressed files, keep a larger amount of archive files, etc.